# Recovering El Gamal secret key from signatures

Tags: elgamal-signature

Assume out of a set of ElGamal signatures, I've discovered that two have the same y i.e. $signature_{1}$ on $m_{1}$ = $(y,s_{1})$ and $signature_{2}$ on $m_{2}$ = $(y,s_{2})$.

The public keys for $signature_{1}$ and $signature_{2}$ and messages $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ are available.

How can I recover the secret keys from this information?

Comment: With how small the parameters are, just use brute force.

Comment: When the nonce is reused you can simply solve those two equations for the private key.

Comment: @CodesInChaos post a solution and get the 50 points.

Comment: @Kairos Since this is a duplicate it has been closed and your bounty refunded. If you want to, you can offer a bounty on the duplicate.